# Comunicación entre componentes ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, componentes

Me ayudan, por favor?
tengo dos componentes hermanos, uno que muestra los comentarios de cada estado y otro donde puedo agregar un comentario al estado correspondiente.

componente  `<Estados>`
el componente estados recibe la lista de estados desde su padre y la renderiza en el hook currentEstado, este tiene dos componentes hijos que hacen la función de mostrar los comentarios asociados a el estado y escribir el comentario asociado al estado

```
const Estados = (props) => {
    const [estadosState, setCurrentEstado] = useState(props.estados)
    const addComentario = (comentario, id) => {
       estadosState.map(e =>{
            if(e.id == id) {
                e.comentariosEstado.push(comentario)
            }
        })
    }
return (
        <Fragment>
            <h2> lista</h2>
            <ul>
                {
                    estadosState.length > 0 ?
                    estadosState.map((item, index) =>
                            <li key={index}>
                                {item.estado}
                                <Comentarios comentarios={item.comentariosEstado}>
                                </Comentarios>
                                <EscribirComentarios
                                    id={item.id}
                                    addComentario={addComentario}>

                                </EscribirComentarios>

                            </li>
                        ) : (
                            <h2>No hay comentarios aún {props.estados.length}</h2>
                        )
                }
            </ul>
        </Fragment>

    );
}
```

tengo el componente `<comentarios>`  este componente me ayuda a renderizar los comentarios asociados a cada estado, en una iteración realizada previamente en el componente padre `<Estados>`

```
const Comentarios = (props) => {
    console.log('comentarios', props.comentarios)
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <ul>
                {
                props.comentarios.map((comentario, index) => 
                    <li key={index}>
                        <small>{comentario.nombre}</small>
                        <p>{comentario.comentario}</p>
                    </li>
                )
                }
            </ul>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Y tengo el componente `<escribir-comentario>`
Este componente no es más que un formulario que manda un comentario y en el método addComentario() se le agrega la lógica, y listo.
en teoría funciona porque se agregan estados, y se visualizan, pero cuando voy a agregar un comentario asociados a un estado, el en el log funciona, hace el push a la lista, pero no el componente `<Comentarios>`  no me renderiza la lista completa, quisiera que me ayudaran con este tema, yo creo que es porque no uso el concepto de hooks correctamente, pero soy nuevo en esto.

Gracias.

```
  const EscribirComentarios = (props) => {

   const { handleSubmit, register } = useForm();
   const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
       props.addComentario(data, props.id)
       //limpiar campos
       e.target.reset();

   }
   return( 
       <React.Fragment>
           <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="containerEscribirComentaro">
               <div className="InputEscribirComentario">
                   <input
                       name="comentario"
                       ref={
                           register({
                               required: { value: true, message: 'Comentario obligatorio' }
                           })
                       }
                   />
               </div>
               <div className="submitEscribirEstado">
                   <input
                       type="submit"
                       value="Comentar"
                   />
               </div>
           </form>
        </React.Fragment>
   )
}
```

**EDITADO**

Si, el componente padre no está interviniendo en el método de agregar comentarios al estado, este es el padre `<app.js>`

```
function App() {
  const estados = [
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      nombre: 'Juan Rodriguez',
      estado: 'Este es un estado de información en ejemplo.',
      comentariosEstado: [
        { id: uuidv4(), comentario: 'Este es un comentario del estado', nombre: 'Elena' },
        { id: uuidv4(), comentario: 'Este es un comentario del estado', nombre: 'Elena' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      nombre: 'Martha Fernández',
      estado: 'Este es un estado de información en ejemplo 2.',
      comentariosEstado: [
        { id: uuidv4(), comentario: 'Este es un comentario del estado 2', nombre: 'Camilo' },
        { id: uuidv4(), comentario: 'Este es un comentario del estado 2', nombre: 'Luffy' }
      ]
    }
  ]
  const [estadosList, setEstadosList] = useState(estados)

  const armarEstados = (estado) =>{
    // después se genera un random para el estado.nombre.
    estado.id = uuidv4()
    estado.nombre = "Camilo F." 
    estado.comentariosEstado = [] 
  }

  const addEstado = (estado) => {
    // estado.id  = uuidv4()
    armarEstados(estado)
    setEstadosList([
      ...estadosList,
      estado
    ])
    
  }
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <EscribirEstados addEstado={addEstado}></EscribirEstados>
      <Estados estados={estadosList}></Estados>
    </React.Fragment>

  );
}
```

Comment: puedes agregar el componente padre ? necesito saber como están llegando los datos para poder ayudarte

Comment: entiendo que no este interviniendo, pero si yo te doy una solucion a tu problema puede que tengas que refactorizar codigo que no esta aca y eso llevaria a que vos preguntes otra vez, por eso necesito saber de donde vienen los datos para tener una idea mas clara de como poder resolver dicho problema

Comment: Listo, ya agregue el componente padre y como se genera el flujo completo.

Comment: ok, estoy preparando una respuesta, en breve la estaré publicando

Comment: Dale, estoy pendiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se vé que aún estas en etapa de desarrollo, pero con esta modificación podrás avanzar y seguir mejorando tu código.

Modifica la función `addComentario` del componente `Estados` de la siguiente forma:

```
const addComentario = (comentario, id) => {
             let copyObj = {   
                  id: uuidv4(), 
                  comentario: comentario.comentario, 
                  nombre: 'usuario en sesion' 
             }
             let copyEstados = estadosState.map(e =>{
                   if(e.id === id) {
                       e.comentariosEstado.push(copyObj);
                       return Object.assign({}, e, {comentariosEstado:e.comentariosEstado} )
                   } else {
                       return e;
                       }
                   })
             setCurrentEstado(copyEstados);
}
```

Ya habías creado una copia de todo el estado con `map`, solo se agregó el nuevo valor de la propiedad `comentariosEstado` para cada estado de información, es decir cada elemento de tu estado:

```
Object.assign({}, e, {comentariosEstado:e.comentariosEstado} )
```

Este nuevo valor es todo el array `comentariosEstado`, ya lo tenias listo cuando codificaste el `push`:

```
e.comentariosEstado.push(copyObj);
```

Por último se complemento el nuevo objeto `comentarios`, con el nuevo `id` que se supone se debe generar y el usuario que se supone que está en sesión:

```
let copyObj = {   
                id: uuidv4(), 
                comentario: comentario.comentario, 
                nombre: 'usuario en sesion' 
              }
```

Finalmente se hace el re-render con la función `setCurrentEstado` y la nueva copia del Estado:

```
setCurrentEstado(copyEstados);
```

Recuerda importar el modulo `uuid` en el componente `Estados`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las mejoras en el uso del código, eso era lo que me restaba por hacer, hacer el re render del hook con el props como propiedad. ```setCurrentEstado(copyEstados);```

Comment: Muy bien, si te ayudo la respuesta no olvides votar por ella, con esto el sitio se mantendrá bien documentado, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

el primer error que observo es como estas manejando el hook `useState`, no es buena practica que el dato del `useState`, valga la redundancia, venga directamente de los props,
igualmente, en el componente `<Estados/>` no haria falta agregar un `useState` ya que los datos vienen directamente desde el padre, al componente `<Estados/>` yo lo haria de la siguiente manera

```
const Estados = props => {

const { estados } = props

const addComentario = (comentario, id) => {
  estados.map(e => {
    if (e.id == id) {
      e.comentariosEstado.push(comentario)
    }
  })
}

return (
  <Fragment>
    <h2>
      lista
    </h2>
    <ul>
      {estados.length > 0 ?  estados.map((item, index)=> 
        <li key={index}>
        {item.estado}
          <Comentarios comentarios={item.comentariosEstado} />
          <EscribirComentarios
            id={item.id}
            addComentario={addComentario}
          />
        </li>
        ): (
          <h2>
            No hay comentarios aún {estados.length}
          </h2>
        )}
    </ul>
  </Fragment>
);
}
```

como podras ver, el atributo estados que estabas pasando al componente `<Estados/>` ya no hace falta guardarlo en el estado del componente, y quedaria un codigo mas limpio,
ahora bien, estas diciendo que el problema es que no se muestran los datos a la hora de agregar un nuevo comentario, lo que yo haria es agregar un `useEffect` al componente padre, lo haria de esta forma

```
function App() {
  const estados = [
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      nombre: 'Juan Rodriguez',
      estado: 'Este es un estado de información en ejemplo.',
      comentariosEstado: [
        { id: uuidv4(), comentario: 'Este es un comentario del estado', nombre: 'Elena' },
        { id: uuidv4(), comentario: 'Este es un comentario del estado', nombre: 'Elena' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      nombre: 'Martha Fernández',
      estado: 'Este es un estado de información en ejemplo 2.',
      comentariosEstado: [
        { id: uuidv4(), comentario: 'Este es un comentario del estado 2', nombre: 'Camilo' },
        { id: uuidv4(), comentario: 'Este es un comentario del estado 2', nombre: 'Luffy' }
      ]
    }
  ]
  const [estadosList, setEstadosList] = useState(estados)

  //simplemente hacemos que el componente se vuelva a renderizar cuando haya un cambio 
  //en el array de estados 
  useEffect(()=>{},[estadosList])

  const armarEstados = (estado) =>{
    // después se genera un random para el estado.nombre.
    estado.id = uuidv4()
    estado.nombre = "Camilo F." 
    estado.comentariosEstado = [] 
  }

  const addEstado = (estado) => {
    // estado.id  = uuidv4()
    armarEstados(estado)
    setEstadosList([
      ...estadosList,
      estado
    ])

  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <EscribirEstados addEstado={addEstado}></EscribirEstados>
      <Estados estados={estadosList}></Estados>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

de esa forma hacemos que cuando haya un cambio en la lista de estados, se vuelva a renderizar, puedes informarte mas sobre los hooks en la pagina oficial de react, son de mucha ayuda a la hora de usar componentes funcionales en react, otra cosa, cuando un componente no necesita hijos, puedes hacer unsa sola etiqueta

```
//esta porcion de codigo se puede simplificar de la sugiente manera 
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <EscribirEstados addEstado={addEstado}></EscribirEstados>
      <Estados estados={estadosList}></Estados>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

return (
    <>
      <EscribirEstados addEstado={addEstado} />
      <Estados estados={estadosList} />
    </>
  );
```

espero que hayas poder solucionado tu problema, cualquier pregunta ya sabes

Comment: Hola, gracias, hice los cambios correspondientes y tomé nota de las mejoras en el código, pero de igual manera no renderiza bien la información, no sé si es porque se le está haciendo push al props, y no directamente esoy utilizando un método de hooks, por eso el   useEffect(()=>{},[estadosList]) no renderiza en sí.

Comment: el array de datos es estatico, eso va a quedar asi en la aplicacion o pensas traerlo desde un backend ?

Comment: Por ahora estoy utilizando el mock, pero después eso irá a un backend en node.  De igual manera aún ando entendiendo como trabajar con hooks, y el cómo renderizo ese componente nieto

Comment: estoy haciendo una muestra en codebox, ahorita paso link, cuando traigas los datos desdel el back, ten cuidado con los pre-renderizados, puede que tengas problemas de memoria si caes en un bug